# Filtering array objects for same key with multiple values in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an array of objects stored in 'component' variable

```
component=[{id:1,type:Comp1},{id:2,type:Comp2},{id:3,type:Comp3},{id:4,type:Comp4},{id:5,type:Comp5}]
```

I want to filter it by type 'Comp1' and 'Comp2'. I tried the following code

```
this.filterComponent=[{id:1,type:Comp1},{id:2,type:Comp2}];
for(let i=0;i<this.filterComponent.length;i++)
 this.component=  this.component.filter(ob => ob.type == this.filterComponenet[i].type)
```

But it works only for a single value(if filteredComponent contains only one object). For instance,

```
this.filterComponent=[{id:1,type:Comp1}]
```

How to make it work for multiple values. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're swallowing the previous filter's result, you should keep track, for example with the function `concat` or even with an additional array.

You can also use the function `filter` as follow:

```
this.filterComponent = [{id:1,type:Comp1},{id:2,type:Comp2}];
this.component = this.component.filter(({type}) => this.filterComponenet.some(({type: t}) => t === type));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```js
var component=[{id:1,type:'Comp1'},{id:2,type:'Comp2'},{id:3,type:'Comp3'},{id:4,type:'Comp4'},{id:5,type:'Comp5'}];

var out = [];

for(i=0; i < component.length; i++){
 if(component[i].type == 'Comp1' || component[i].type == 'Comp2'){
  out.push(component[i]);
 }
}

console.log(out);
```